# What does ("(?i)[^aeiou]", "") do to find vowels in a string?

Tags: java

I saw this post on CodeWars as an answer in java to finding number of vowels in a word:

```
    public static int getCount(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
    }

}
```

Howeve I don't undestand the syntax around this part:

```
    return str.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
```

I understand it finds the length after doing something to manipulate the string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

String's [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method takes a regular expression as the first parameter, and replaces any matches with the second parameter. In this case, it is being given the regular expression `(?i)[^aeiou]`, which matches all non-vowels, and replaces them with `""`, an empty string. Then it returns the length of the resulting string,.

Thus this is finding the number of vowels by stripping off all *non*-vowels, and counting how many characters remain.

The regular expression can be broken down like this:

- `(?i)` -- a flag indicating that this is case insensitive, so it will match upper and lower case characters alike.
- `[^aeiou]` -- matches characters which are *not* `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`. (The `^` inverts the matching.)

Comment: You're welcome. The linked 'duplicate' will explain more about how regular expressions work, but I figured it was more useful to explain how it worked with 'replaceAll' to solve the problem.